# Recursively read name file in a folder then create new thumb in html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm very new to html, php and js so maybe this could seem a dumb question... please help anyway :)

This is the scenario:

- I have a folder that contains some image files.
- I have a html page were I want to display those files.

I'd like not to manually repeat the same command for each image, but to have something tha does it for me.

In my html there is something like this:

```html
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="pick-my-image">
    <a href="cool_bag.html" class="thumb-overlay"> <!-- html page should be created automatically -->
      <img src="myfolder/cool_bag.jpg"> <!-- this file name should be picked up automatically -->
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="portfolio-description">
     <a href="cool_bag.html">
       <h6>Cool things</h6>
       <h5 class="portfolio-name" ><strong>Cool bag</strong></h5><!-- This should be the name of the image. Actually I don't know how to generate it  -->
     </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

This code generates a thumbnail in a portfolio gallery page. Every thumbnail, if clicked, should redirect to its page (cool_bag.html in this case)

Thanks to all that will answer!

Stef

Comment: To get each image you're going to want to use a For Each loop in PHP to get each image in the folder. If you're wanting each specific image to have it's own .html page (cool_dog.jpg, cool_bag.html) you're going to most likely have to use a database. Unless, you can guarantee all the .html files are going to be the same as the .jpg, then you can just frankenstein them together. If you're new to this, start here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Using a database.. Do you mean I should upload images in the db?

Comment: All the pages should be identical. Only images and text content should vary